# How do you add item to the beginning of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, slider, carousel

the code is in this codesandbox.io - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slider-forked-wu0q6

```
    if (newActiveIndex === slides[slides.length - 1].index) {
      const { slides } = this.state;

      // index (10-3) to (10)
      const add = slides.slice(slides.length - 3);

      const newSlides = slides.unshift(add);
      console.log("newSlides", newSlides);

      this.setState({
        slides: newSlides
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        slides: slides
      });
    }
  };
```

I tried using unshift method, but when i console log it, it returns a number and not an array. what i want is
[0,1,2,3,4,5] becomes [3,4,5,0,1,2]

Answer (score 0):

You used two component each one have a state.
When you change the state from the dots component the image component has no idea that there is a change.
So the solution is to add the active state in your App.js and pass it as props for both components => if you change it from dots the image will have the latest active index

```js
import React from "react";
import ImageSlider from "./components/ImageSlider";
import SliderDots from "./components/SliderDots";
import "./styles.css";

const SliderData = require("./SliderData.json");
/**
 * Convert this to class since you will be working with class!
 */
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedIndex: 2
  };

  setSelectedIndex = (i) => {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex: i });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ImageSlider
          slides={SliderData}
          selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
          setSelectedIndex={this.setSelectedIndex}
        />
        <SliderDots
          slides={SliderData}
          selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
          setSelectedIndex={this.setSelectedIndex}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, 
but isnt in my App.js I have the same props of active?
`<ImageSlider slides={SliderData} active={2} />` `<SliderDots slides={SliderData} active={2} />`
yes please, i'd like to know how to implement it

Comment: I edited the answer , your app.js should look like the snippet , now you need to use the selectedIndex to choose the selected image , and on dot component when clicking you call the this.props.setSelectedIndex(index) : index is the index of clicked dot

Comment: the idea is to share the same state between the component => once this state changes the two child component will-rerender

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to do on my own first, if i'm stuck.. i'll make a new comment below.. thanks again!! @Borni.Mr

Comment: you're welcome , start from tha App.js

Comment: I manage to do the jump to x slide, now i'm having trouble using the `window.scrollTo()`, can you help me @Borni.Mr

Comment: @Bernard could you please edit your code sandbox with the latest version when using scrollTo

Comment: I've already update to the latest version

Comment: can you help me with how to create an infinite carousel?